# How to use virtual machines in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc

I was earlier using Windows Vista. Since some old but useful application didn't work properly in Windows Vista, I was using Windows XP virtual machine with "Microsoft Virtual PC 2007".

Yesterday I installed windows 7 and I was hoping that same virtual disk image can be used on Windows 7. I checked the website and it says Windows 7 comes with cool new Windows XP mode but I checked and found that **it works only if I have hardware-assisted virtualization (which I don't)**.

So I skipped Windows XP mode and installed so called "Windows Virtual PC" (note: NOT microsoft virtual PC). But it refused to start with the same reason (no hardware assisted virtualization).

Lastly I tried good old "Microsoft Virtual PC 2007". It installed successfully but when I tried to run it, I received an error:

[image]

It gave me an option to check for solutions which I did but it said:

[image]

Windows 7 may be cool but the truth is that I was able to do something yesterday which I cant today. Do you know any solution?

Answer (score 3):

OK. I googled around a bit and [this post](http://silverstr.ufies.org/blog/archives/001076.html) told me that I had trouble because I installed "Windows Virtual PC" first and **then** installed "Microsoft Virtual PC 2007".

It turns out that if "Windows Virtual PC" is installed then "Microsoft Virtual PC 2007" is incompatible with Windows 7 but if you remove former, later works fine.

Weird!

Comment: +1 Interesting you went through this. It adds a precious bit of information to my notebook; One cannot have both.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try Sun's [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) - it's free and works great on many operating systems.

Comment: Since I already has virtual hard disks created with Virtual PC, I didn't want to start all-over with new software. Fortunately I found the solution. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: not to worry, VBox supports MSVPC disk images.